# ShellExecute in Windows Embedded

Tags: c++, windows, embedded, shellexecute

I am using

```
ShellExecute(NULL,"open","control.exe","ncpa.cpl","c:\\windows\\system32\\",SW_NORMAL);
```

to open the Network Connections window. That is working on my system which has Windows XP on it. But when I make a build for the machine on which this program has to run it doesn't work. It has Windows Embedded on it. I guess it's because there is no control.exe in Windows Embedded.

So I tried running

```
ShellExecute(NULL,"open","Rundll32.exe","ncpa.cpl","c:\\windows\\system32\\",SW_NORMAL);
```

but that is not working. It returns 42 so its success, but still nothing happens. I tried various other options like using "ncpa.cpl,," and using "Rundll32.exe Shell32.dll" instead of "Rundll32.exe" but that doesn't work either. How can I use ShellExecute so that it will work on both on my machine as well as on Windows Embedded. Even if there is a solution which will only work on Windows Embedded that is fine since I will just #define it.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to skip `ShellExecute` and simply load and invoke the control panel directly, using its [CPlApplet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776392%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) entry point. The protocol that needs to be followed is documented (from the control panel's point of view) [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144185%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Then you wouldn't need any external helper app to launch the control panel; you'd just host it right in your process.

Comment: Sorry but, not really sure how to do that lol. Can you give a brief example how I can use CPIApplet to implement this. I am basically  looking for a single line of code which can bring up that "Network Connections" window. CPIApplet kinda feels too complicated just to bring up one window. Is it possible to do, if not with ShellExecute function than any other function?

Comment: @user807665, if you're missing control.exe, there's not really a one-liner for this; you'll need to reimplement a portion of what control.exe does, which is what the MSDN documentation documents.

Comment: I had a look at CPIApplet but I think it's too much of a hassle. I tried using something else actually. Made a batch file to open up ncpa.cpl. Then I simply used                                                                ShellExecute(NULL,"open","timepass.bat",NULL,NULL,SW_HIDE);                     which worked perfectly on Windows XP, but did not work on Windows embedded. What could be the problem here? I made sure timepass.bat was in the place where it needs to be(same location as the exe file). For Windows Embedded do I need to add something extra?

Comment: Most likely windows embedded is missing the exe file that would normally host control panel applets. Hence why you need to use the `CPlApplet` entry point directly.